# RestKit: Getting HTTP status code when a request fails

Tags: iphone, ios, http, restkit

I'm using RestKit in an iOS app and I need to have special handling for certain HTTP error codes. How can the the response HTTP status code be checked inside of `request:didFailLoadWithError:`? Is there some entry in the `userInfo` dictionary of the `NSError`?

I couldn't find anything in the [`RKRequestDelegate` documentation](http://restkit.org/api/0.9/Protocols/RKRequestDelegate.html#//api/name/request%3adidFailLoadWithError%3a).

Here's the interface for the delegate method:

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For people using the new version of RESTkit and objectManager, you can fetch the statuscode from the `RKObjectRequestOperation`:

`operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode`

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that `didFailLoadWithError:` is not called for HTTP errors. The `request:didLoadResponse:` method is still called for HTTP errors, so the response (and hence the status codes) are available.

Answer (score 1):

The `statusCode` property found on `RKResponse` works for me:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error 
{
    switch ([[objectLoader response] statusCode]) {
        case 409:
    ...

}
```

Comment: I'm just using the RKClient, so I get notified through the RKRequestDelegate, not the ObjectManagerDelegate. All the RKRequestDelegate provides for errors is the RKRequest and an NSError.

Comment: RKRequest has a response property in 0.10.3.