# How to send some data in http header with restkit

Tags: ios, restkit

I need send some data in http header each time when I do request to server (whith get and post methods). I am using RKObjectManager from restkit. Also I need check status returned by server (401, 200, 404 e.t.c). Does anybody know the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need to send custom headers with your requests, i'd suggest to use the `RKClient` property `HTTPHeaders`, for example:

```
[[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] client] HTTPHeaders] setValue:myValue
                                                          forKey:myHeaderName];
```

For the status code, see my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218743/restkit-getting-http-status-code-when-a-request-fails).

Comment: More succinctly: `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client setValue:myValue forHTTPHeaderField:myHeaderName];`

Comment: Does this set the header for all requests or only for one?  I'm looking for a way to set a header for only a single request. (nvr mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115565/custom-headers-per-request-in-restkit)

Answer (score 17):

in version 0.20.0rc1 you can use the following code:

```
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:myHeaderName value:myValue];
```